# What is meant by Transaction not started in SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

Here are the few lines of response of 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;'

---

```
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 58EC54C6
Purge done for trx's n:o < 58EC54C3 undo n:o < 0
History list length 2420
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 58EC51E6, not started
MySQL thread id 520131, OS thread handle 0x7f0db930e700, query id 24011015 108.89.56.87 xyz
---TRANSACTION 58EC527E, not started
MySQL thread id 520061, OS thread handle 0x7f0dbb596700, query id 24011370 108.89.56.87 xyz
---TRANSACTION 58EC53AC, not started
MySQL thread id 520065, OS thread handle 0x7f0dbb28a700, query id 24012094 108.89.56.87 xyz
---TRANSACTION 58EC50CE, not started
MySQL thread id 520109, OS thread handle 0x7f0dbba69700, query id 24010431 108.89.56.87 xyz    ---TRANSACTION 58EC51E8, not started
MySQL thread id 520123, OS thread handle 0x7f0dbb4d3700, query id 24011016 108.89.56.87 xyz    ---TRANSACTION 58EC51D0, not started
MySQL thread id 520072, OS thread handle 0x7f0db865c700, query id 24010944 108.89.56.87 xyz
---TRANSACTION 58EC5184, not started
MySQL thread id 520058, OS thread handle 0x7f0db8c74700, query id 24010807 108.89.56.87 xyz
```

I want to know what this 'Transaction transId, not started' means? Does any query failed to execute?

I am using innodb. also I am not manually starting transaction. It is considering automatically transaction because I am issuing update query on a table having bulk data. and ya there are getting hundreads of mysql update query on this single table in 5-10 mins.

Please let me know what exactly 'Transaction not started' means? Is it showing failed query or just a normal log?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first time a thread (~connection) needs to lock some data during a transaction, a transaction "object" (~context) is created. The transaction "object" is not destroyed at the end of the transaction, it would be reused in case a new transaction is started by the same thread.

Each transaction showing as `not started` is a transaction "object" owned by a thread which is not *currently* inside a transaction (more precisely, which does not need to maintain a separate context for a transaction).

The `thread id` is the one that shows in the `Id`column when you issue a `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

This is nothing to worry about, actually this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on Internet:

> When does Innodb Start Transaction ?
>
> January 11, 2011 By Peter Zaitsev
>
> 9 Comments inShare1
>
> When does Innodb Start Transaction ? The answer looks obvious – when you issue “BEGIN” command. This is however wrong answer from
>   engine point of you. Run “SHOW INNODB STATUS” and you will see “not
>   started” status in transaction list.

from [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/01/11/when-does-innodb-start-transaction/)

> For each of connections for MySQL there will be ether not started state if there is no active  Innodb transaction for this connection,
>   or ACTIVE if transaction is active. Note transaction can be  active
>   even if connection is in "Sleep" stage - if it is multiple statement
>   transaction. Innodb also  will print OS thread_id and process id which
>   may be helpful if you would like to use gdb to connect to  running
>   mysqld for troubleshooting purposes and similar things. Also
>   transaction status is reported  which is basically what transaction is
>   doing it can be "fetching rows", "updating" and couple of other 
>   values.

the [source](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/)